# Understanding 「家へ帰る間に、傘を忘れてきたのに気づいた。」

Tags: translation, particles, relative-tense

Consider

> 家へ帰る間に、傘を忘れてきたのに気づいた。
>
> While going home, I noticed that I had come without my umbrella.

**Questions:**

1. Just clarifying: のに here is *not* meant as a conjuctive (meaning "although",  "despite"), correct? Instead it's being used as 「(((傘を忘れてきた)の)に)」, correct? That is, first の nominalizes 傘を忘れてきた, and then に is tacked on the end to be used adverbially with 気づいた.
2. Is 「傘を忘れてきた」considered a subordinate clause in this sentence? If so: since it's in the past tense, does that mean that it is happening in the *relative past* of when the main verb (気づいた) is happening (so that the 忘れてきた happened *even earlier* than the 気づいた)?  Or are they both uttered with the reference point being the present moment (as in English)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes it's a subordinate clause, and 忘れてきた is in the relative past. It becomes relative present when describing something that happens  on his way home.

   - 雪が降っているのに気づいた。
     I noticed it was snowing.
   - 傘を忘れているのに気づいた。
     (ている for continuation-of-state)

Note that the use of 間に is not natural here. You can say 家に帰っていると or 家に帰る途中で.

Comment: Doesn't 家に帰っていると imply that you noticed the missing umbrella when you got home rather than on the way home? I would have translated it literally as "upon having returned". What am I missing?